# Why doesn't .on() method execute the first handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var x;
userList.on( "mouseover", "li", function(e) {
    console.log('1');
    x = setTimeout( function() { 
        doThis();
    }, 700);
},function(){
    console.log('3');
    clearInterval(x);
});
userList.on( "mouseleave", "li", function(e) {
    showProfile.css('display', 'none');
});
```

Now whenever i'm hovering over the userlist it shows me `console.log('3')` what i'm doing wrong in this case ?

Comment: using `hover` function this code will be much handy,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are confusing `hover` method which accepts 2 handlers(one for `mouseenter` and one for the `mouseleave` event) with the `on` method. You should just pass one callback function to the `on` method. The first function in this case is used as the optional `data` parameter and the second function is used as the handler:

```
.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )
```

`data` property of the `event` object refers to the passed function. You can invoke the function using `()` invocation operator:

```
userList.on( "mouseover", "li", function(e) {
    console.log('1');
    x = setTimeout( function() { 
        doThis();
    }, 700);
},function(event) {
    event.data(); // calls the first function
    // ...
});
```

Also note that `mouseenter` and `mouseover` are 2 different events. You should either listen to `mouseover/mouseout` or `mouseenter/mouseleave`.

And for clearing timeouts set by `setTimeout` function you should use `clearTimeout`, `clearInterval` is used for clearing intervals set by `setInterval` function.

```
var x;
userList.on({
   mouseenter: function() {
       x = setTimeout( function() { 
          doThis();
       }, 700);
   },
   mouseleave: function() {
      clearTimeout(x);
      // showProfile.css('display', 'none');
      // ...
   }
}, "li");
```

Comment: How to do if mouseover and mouseleaves on 500 miliseconds. Than it must not trigger doThis() function.

Comment: Thanks mate, i added `userList.on( "mouseleave", "li", function(e) {
    showProfile.css('display', 'none');
   clearInterval(x);
});`